# managedCUDA: Running own kernel - Error: InvalidValue

Tags: c#, cuda

I'm new in programming CUDA, and I'm trying to load CUDA kernel in C# with managedCUDA but I'm still getting an error during calling kernel method.

```
ErrorInvalidValue: This indicates that one or more of the parameters passed to the API call is not within an acceptable range of values.
```

I'm getting this error even when I call `kernel.Run()` or `kernel.RunAsync((new CudaStream()).Stream)` - when my kernel does not have any parameter.

Does anybody know what's wrong? Or can anybody point me to the right direction please... Thans a lot for any help!

My **kernel.cu** code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

extern "C"  {
    __global__ void func()
    {
        const int numThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
        const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

**kernel.ptx**:

```
    .version 1.4
    .target sm_11, map_f64_to_f32
    // compiled with C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin/../open64/lib//be.exe
    // nvopencc 4.1 built on 2014-03-14
    ...some more comments...

    .file   1   "<filename>.gpu"
     ...next 33 .file(s)

    .entry func
    {
    .loc    15  52  0
$LDWbegin_func:
    .loc    15  57  0
    exit;
$LDWend_func:
    } // func
```

and C# program:

```
        string resName;
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
            resName = "kernel_64.ptx";
        else
            resName = "kernel.ptx";

        string resNamespace = "signalViewer.CUDA";
        string resource = resNamespace + "." + resName;
        Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
        if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentException("Kernel not found in resources.");

        CudaKernel func= ctx.LoadKernelPTX(stream, "func");

        dim3 threads = new dim3(512, 1);
        dim3 blocks = new dim3(N / (int)threads.x, 1);

        func.BlockDimensions = threads;
        func.GridDimensions = blocks;
        func.RunAsync((new CudaStream()).Stream);
        //func.Run();
```

Comment: What is the value of N?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jez! N was lower (64) than number of blocks (512) so in final there were zero number of blocks (64/512), I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jez - I had number of blocks equal to zero

```
dim3 threads = new dim3(512, 1);
dim3 blocks = new dim3(N / (int)threads.x, 1);
```

**N was 64**

Better solution is:

```
    int maxThreads = Math.Min(ctx.GetDeviceInfo().MaxThreadsPerBlock, N);
    dim3 threads = new dim3(maxThreads, 1);
    dim3 blocks = new dim3((N + maxThreads - 1)  / maxThreads, 1);
```

Comment: Usually the number of blocks is computed by ceiling the floating point division or more conveniently in integer arithmetic: blocks = ((N + maxThreads - 1) / maxThreads). This number will always be >= 1. You then also need to check inside the kernel if the current threadID is larger than N!

Comment: Thanks @kunzmi, editing post by your suggestion and my code too :-}